# Clustered vs covering index

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing

Consider the following table in SQL Server 2008:

```
LanguageCode  varchar(10)
Language      nvarchar(50)
```

LanguageCode participates in relationships, so I cannot create a primary key index that includes both columns (LanguageCode, Language).

If I put a primary clustered key on LanguageCode, of course I can't include Language in the index (covering index). This means that I will have to create a second index for Language, or run the risk of having duplicates in it (plus force a table scan to retrieve its value).

Further, MS's documentation (as well as experts on the subject) indicate that a table should **ideally** have a clustered index.

In this case, a non-clustered covering index (LanguageCode, Language) would not only ensure that Language is unique, but would avoid the table scan. However, there would be no "ideal" clustered index.

Is this one of those cases where having no clustered index is in fact ideal?

**Edit based on feedback:**

The only query I wish to run is:

```
SELECT Language, LanguageCode FROM Languages where Language="EN"
```

Comment: will your language table ever participate in joins?

Comment: @Quassnoi yes - it will join on LanguageCode (matching its relationship)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clustered index, by definition, covers all columns.

If you create a `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` on `LanguageCode` and a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `Language`, it will allow you to search a language both by its code and its name with a single lookup, and, in addition, make `Language` unique.

Comment: @Quassnoi that's what I did originally. After your help yesterday, I have been going through a DB and optimizing its indexes. I was trying to get away with 1 index here since in reality, I will only search by Language.

Comment: @Ian: you cannot use a single index for looking up two different columns independently. An index relies on sorting, and you cannot sort on two columns at once.

Comment: @Ian: search on `Language` or search and join on `Language`? Since `LanguageCode` is referred to by the foreign keys, seems you will want to join on it as well.

Comment: @Quassnoi Join is on LanguageCode, lookup is on Language.

Comment: @IanC: then you want two indexes. Indexes are used in joins as well.

Comment: @Quassnoi for sure they do... so, in other words, I was spot on to start with. Good!

Comment: @Quassnoi just remember, the join is on the PK anyway. So index #2 is only going to give me uniqueness, with no other benefit (in this case).

Comment: @Quassnoi don't forget, if we create a single index on 3 columns (a, b, c), technically this is a 3-layer index, fully sorted by a, b, c. So technically we could use a single index for looking up n columns (assuming proper covering, etc.).

Comment: @IanC: an index on `(a, b, c)` cannot be used for looking up on `b` or `c`: it's not sorted on these columns as a whole.

Comment: @Quassnoi You mean it won't be able to do the following?: WHERE a=? and b=? and c=?

Comment: @IanC: yes it will, but without `a = ?` it won't. I believe you have two different type of queries: first type searches for a user-provided `LanguageName`, the second type joins on `LanguageCode`. You need two different indexes for these queries.

Comment: @Quassnoi re the index, of course :). I agree with you re. the indexes. I have two indexes. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no need to include columns on a clustered index. Since the clustered index is "the data", all columns are automatically included.
2. If you have a need to search by Language and/or ensure its uniqueness, then definitely create an additional index on it.

Comment: thanks - I see your point re. the clustered index being the data. I looked up SQL Server's storage system. As a side note, I wonder how many databases this hold true for.

Comment: @IanC: it's true for every database that supports clustered indexes. Of the major ones it's `SQL Server`, `Oracle` (which calls it *index-organized table*) and `InnoDB` (one of `MySQL`'s storage engines).

Comment: @Quassnoi What about PostgreSQL? I know Caché uses a different system. It's still my fav. DB, apart from the price tag.

Comment: @Ian: PostgreSQL does not support clustered indexes.

Comment: @Quassnoi Interesting. It seems to fair well in benchmarks, though (for what they are worth).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the nature of the subject (which I'm guessing is languages spoken by humans), indexing *for performance* is going to be irrelevant. If you had 100 languages, and each row took 120 bytes (psuedo-factoring in varchar headers, null bitmasks, and whatnot), you'd have 12,000 bytes of data, which fits on two 8k pages. SQL will not bother to use indexes on anything that small, it'll just table scan the whole thing (2 pages) and brute force it, requiring less time than can readily be measured.

Indexing to ensure uniqueness, sure, I do it all the time. But for performance, until you hit 3 pages (or is it 4), it just doesn't matter. (Which will happen if you're tracking programming languages, 'cause there's a dozen new ones every week or so.)

Comment: this totally depends on the queries the @op will be using. See here: http://explainextended.com/2009/06/22/indexing-tiny-tables/